Advice for developing multiuser enterprise dApp with encrypted data on-chain?
I am exploring the possibility of using Solana to develop an enterprise dApp where-by a single entity would subscribe and pay for the service but allow for multiple user accounts to interact with the application.
As an example, consider an Enterprise Application, such as Slack, where a company or organization wants to allow users to access the system but not require each user to maintain a Solana wallet of their own.  The client organization, via an admin, should be able to subscribe to the service using their local currency, so a Solana wallet would be setup for them, controlled by the Enterprise App, ultimately funded by subscriber’s subscription fee.
The dApp should keep track of messages without exposing the content.  So I suspect each transaction would store a hash of some sort that would then be used to decrypt data (text, images, etc…) stored on a server controlled by the Enterprise Application.
I’m VERY new to Solana and not sure this would be the best use case for such a system, but I’m curious if it is possible.  I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or links related to exploring this further.
